# Create an Excel chart series using last API office.js

Tags: excel, charts, office365api, office365-apps, office-js

Can somebody tell me if is it possible to create a chart series using API office.js ?
I found no method which can do this in the API documentation !

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to add a series is to modify the Source Data range to include additional rows or columns. That can be achieved via the [Chart](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/chart) object:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var chart = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("mySheet").charts.getItem("myChart"); 
    var biggerData = "A1:C4";
    chart.setData(biggerData, "Columns");
    return ctx.sync(); 
});
```

Comment: This method is ok, if you add only one kind of charts. But what can I do to display for example a xyscatter plot with a ColumnClustered on the same chart !